# check if listbox count changed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have two listboxs in an asp:wizard "in step 2 there is a step before and step after it. By using some code i take some items from the first listbox to the second one 
I want to check if the count of the second one changed. What I can do ?

This is my listbox code

```
<asp:ListBox ID="registerCompCats" runat="server" CssClass="ListBox1"
  ClientIDMode="Static" DataTextField="value" DataValueField="key" Rows="5"  
  size="5" style="width:135px; size:5px;" SelectionMode="Multiple" ></asp:ListBox>

<img id="addCat" src="images/buttons/btn_addCat.jpg" title="Add Category"/>

<asp:ListBox ID="registerCompAcats" runat="server" CssClass="ListBox2"
  ClientIDMode="Static" DataTextField="value" DataValueField="key" Rows="5" 
  size="5" style="width:135px; size:5px; margin-top: 0px;" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

This code works well and move items but after finishing the wizard the second listbox is empty. What I can do?

**EDIT**

that is the java script code that take data from listbox1 to listbox2

```
 $('#addCat').click(function () {
            $(".ListBox1 > option:selected").appendTo(".ListBox2");
            sortlist(".ListBox1 > option");
            sortlist(".ListBox2 > option");
            selectAll();
        });
```

and that is the code behind that check for items and add them to the other list

```
for (int i = 0; i < rc.CategoriesIDs.Count; i++)
        {
            var foundcat = registerCompCats.Items.FindByValue(rc.CategoriesIDs[i].ToString());
            if (foundcat != null)
            {
                registerCompAcats.Items.Add(foundcat);
                registerCompCats.Items.Remove(foundcat);
            }
        }
```

if you need any other code i can post it agian

Comment: That is just markup - do you have some code to go with it?

Comment: As KP said, all this does is tell us that there's a few listboxes there and what their properties are, it doesn't tell us anything about how you're handling this, so we're not able to provide any recommendations.

Comment: Why don't you add selected items on server side using an update panel?

Comment: can you explain it more how i can do it  please ???